# Find the name which has specific extension in linux using grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to `grep` the name which has extension of css from the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/royalslider.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/default/rs-default.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/style.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">" .
```

From the above format i want to `grep` only the names which has extension of .css.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/royalslider.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/default/rs-default.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/static/css/style.min.css?ver=r2d3.7.2">

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Try to indicate what is your input, expected output and what you tried so far. Now it is a bit confusing. Also, do not clarify in comments but in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this command you can extract all `css` files present in your provided sample text/code,

```
grep -o \/[\-a-zA-Z.0-9]*\.css? sample.txt |tr -d '/?'
```

Here is the **explanations** of above command,

```
grep -o \/[\-a-zA-Z.0-9]*\.css? sample.txt
```

`grep` command you will extracting string between `/` and `.css?`

```
tr -d '/?'
```

`tr` command here will omits unwanted characters from output such as `/` and `?` .

Here is the **output** from my console,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following one:

```
grep -o '[^?"]*\.css'
```

`-o` makes grep output only the matching parts. The pattern just searches for a string of non-question-marks and non-double-quotes that ends in ".css".